# Ruby on Rails: How to connect to a mailserver with 'ehlo' instead of 'helo'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mail-server

I have a SMTP server that needs to authenticate with extended smtp (esmtp) and i can't find a way to make my rails app to authenticate with EHLO instead of HELO.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that Rails isn't already doing this?  Digging through the source, Rails delegates to the Mail gem which delegates to `Net::SMTP`.   If you look at the Ruby source for lib/net/smtp.rb, you'll see that at some point it calls a private `do_helo` method which checks the `@esmtp` variable and if true, does ehlo instead of helo. Looking back up at the initialize, it sets `@esmtp` to true by default.  I don't see anywhere that it's getting unset.

Perhaps it's something else?

For the reference `do_helo` in `Net::SMTP`

```
def do_helo(helodomain)
   begin
     if @esmtp
       ehlo helodomain
     else
       helo helodomain
     end
   rescue Net::ProtocolError
     if @esmtp
       @esmtp = false
       @error_occured = false
       retry
     end
     raise
   end
end
```

Comment: it's strange, the company that host the server tells me from the log that the error comes from my app that does a HELO instead of EHLO

Comment: Perhaps there is a ProtocolError on your end causing it to flip the switch to false and retry (as the code suggests)?